# Laravel's created_date, updated_date and Id columns php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am confused about database tables created in the Laravel framework. 
It automatically generated `ID`, `created_at`, and `updated_at` columns for me. 
So, when  I want to retrieve a whole table of database, so I need to create a new model as the previous created table doesn't have `ID`, `created_date` and `updated_date` attributes?

All I am trying to do is pull all data in a particular table and display to user.

Thank you very much in advance and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a migration in laravel you'll see that it's added in

```
           $table->timestamps();
```

inside of the up method, e.g

```
public function up(){
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->timestamps();
}
```

the timestamps are the created_at and updated_at columns that you see inside of the database table. 
If you do not want these added you can simply remove the line

```
 $table->timestamps();
```

before running

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: you do not need to create a new table. If you want to add the ID/created_at or updated at columns to an existing table.

You can then run 

    php artisan make:migration ADD_NEW_COLUMN --table=existing_table

you can then add new columns into an existing table.